# Liouville's theorem and systems in equilibrium

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

This is related to a statement I once came across in Reif, that systems in equilibrium, described by the micro-canonical ensemble,stay in equilibrium.

In the appendix(pg 628), he asserts that, in a system described the density function $\rho (p_i,q_i,t)$ , if for one time $t_c$. the system is such that $\frac{\partial \rho }{\partial q_i} = \frac{\partial \rho }{\partial p_i}=0$ , by virtue of Liouville's theorem, this means $\frac{\partial \rho }{\partial t}=0$ at that $t_c$. He goes on to say that this means that the density distribution will remain constant all over the phase space for all time.Hence, a system that has for any one time achieved equilibrium stays in equilibrium.

However, I can easily make a function that satisfies the given conditions and yet isn't a constant, say $ \rho = (t-t_c)^{2} (\sum_{i} q_i + \sum_{i} p_i)$.

Where am I erring?

Comment: Liouville's theorem doesn't apply to *any* function. The density function must correspond to a valid Hamiltonian system.

Comment: Shouldn't the Hamiltonian determine just the relation between $\dot{p}$  or  $\dot{q}$  and $q$ or $p$.
What I am saying is given a $\rho$, doesn't a Hamiltonian $H$ always exist such that Liouville's theorem is satisfied?
What makes a valid Hamiltonian?

Comment: A Hamiltonian has no restrictions on it's functional form, because we can always use a canonical transformation to change it's form.
So how do we know that the $\rho$ in question does not correspond to a valid hamiltonian. Mathematically, how do we see that it doesn't?

Comment: I suppose since Liouville's theorem states that $d\rho/dt=0$, then the value of $\rho$ at any time $t>t_c$ at the coordinates $q^{\text{obs}}_i, p^{\text{obs}}_i$, can be determined by "walking back" along a path $q_i(t), p_i(t)$ (where $q_i(t)=q^{\text{obs}}_i, p_i(t)=p^{\text{obs}}_i$) and evaluating $\rho(p_i(t_c), q_i(t_c), t_c)$. In the counter-example you give, the only error I can think of is that your probability density looks like its modelling a scenario where systems are "receding to infinity (in phase space)" (for $t<t_c$) and "invading from infinity" (for $t>t_c$).